# Safari browser - Mac vs Windows vs iOS

Tags: safari

Can anyone let me know what is the difference between testing a Safari 5 in Windows vs Mac? Are there significant changes in how the page is rendered between windows vs Mac for the same version of Safari? If I test a page in Windows Safari, can I expect the page works exactly same in Mac Safari as long as Safari version matches?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not significant but there are subtle differences, it's difficult to list them as I think it will depend on the html/css and version.

I have noticed small differences on one of my sites in the past, but as I can't remember the details I've found another [example](http://www.harecoded.com/subtle-differences-between-safari-for-windows-and-mac-96343) that someone has documented.

Anyway, I've satisfied myself that the differences I've seen are too subtle to fully test every release on each machine (the budget is small!), only on major changes.

Answer (score 1):

One small difference for instance is that the iOS version won't allow you autoplay of any media (audio or video) in its html5 player whilst the Windows and Mac versions do.

Answer (score 0):

i notice few thing in windows safari and mac safari,when we choose an image in windows safari then its not display as preview but in mac safari its display as preview before upload.so File reader api is not supporting blog type.